# Cannot find XSL STYLESHEET folder in the Style Library folder

Tags: item-styles, style-library

I would like to create my own custom itemstyle. I would like to follow the following tutorial. One of the steps is to go to the style library and then go to the xsl stylesheets folder. I have a style library folder, but I dont see the xsl stylesheet folder. Do I need to activate some feature to get these folder??

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to activate the publishing infrastructure at the site collection level.